# How do I fix a vacuum leak?

Tags: star-command

I am really tired of losing missions because my captain keeps getting sucked out of my ship because I get hit and then there are vacuum leaks. Is there any way to fix the leaks so my crew don't keep getting sucked into space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vacuum leaks occur when one of our ship's outer walls gets damaged enough to break.  This is usually caused by something hitting your shield hard enough to drop it, too.  If it's anywhere near your crew, they tend to get sucked out.

The simplest way to prevent this is to get your shields back up.  Once all the red bars are refilled, vacuum leaks stop sucking people out, and you can safely repair them.  Keep in mind that if you're doing this in combat, though, that as soon as your shield drops again, the leak comes back if you haven't repaired it.

The Shield Booster works incredibly well for this.  You take the hit, use the Shield Booster, and you have a decent amount of time to get the engineers over to the leak to get it fixed.  It's also a pinch save if your captain was unlucky enough to be close to a leak when it happens.

Once your engineers get enough experience to be able to increase their repair radius, you can also repair it from outside the leak's area of effect.  That's not something you can do at the beginning, though.

Comment: Shield booster? (I have the feeling that I am not optimizing my ship as well as I could be....)

Comment: It's one of the small rooms you can build.  The ability it gives is a rather large chunk of shield restoration.  Comes in extremely handy for keeping your shields up.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow crew members will repair the hull breach.

From [Dtoid](http://www.destructoid.com/very-quick-tips-a-star-command-guide-253019.phtml):

> One of the most useful is the yellow ability to increase the repair
>   AOE, which allows them to repair hull breaches without getting in
>   their proximity and getting sucked out into space.